# Using Regression Analysis to Predict Property Prices

Tags: regression, predictive-models

Hi I'm currently working on a project at my new graduate job, a client has come to ask us to create a model that predicts care home property prices, we have a lot of data on this, such as average house prices in region, number of beds in home, ensuite rooms, property specification. I have all these independent variables which I want to use to predict Property price (we also have some data on property prices). Now originally I wanted to create a sort of regression model similar to work I have done in university, on a software such as Stata, but my data has some percentages e.g. (Ensuite %), some in letters (Purpose built or Conversion).

I have been put in charge of creating this model and am looking for any suggestions, or to bounce some ideas.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What is the money?  Every business problem is really about money.  All of them.  This too.  Are they looking for high costs, low costs, arbitrage, control, or something else?

Comment: They just want us to create a methodology that will predict the property value of a care home, I know this is determined by things like, specification, region, number of beds etc, so I want to use this data to predict property prices

Comment: there are a pile of predictors for prices of properties.  [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/home-value-prediction-2de1c293853c) [link](https://www.data-blogger.com/2017/11/29/house-price-prediction-using-random-forest-classifier/)